# Read a File, String, Int from servlet send by Java Client

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, servlet-3.0

I am sending a request from java client program to Servlet like below,

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/TestWebProject/execute");
HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
httpCon.setRequestMethod("POST");

DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(httpCon.getOutputStream());
out.writeUTF("hello");
out.writeUTF("World");

ByteArrayOutputStream bos;
File baseFile = new File("C:\\Users\\jp\\Desktop\\mdn.txt");

if (!baseFile.exists())
{
    System.out.println("File Not Found Correctly");
}

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(baseFile);

byte[] fileBytes = new byte[1024];
bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

while (true)
{
    int ch = fis.read(fileBytes);

    if (ch != -1)
    {
        bos.write(fileBytes, 0, ch);
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
bos.close();
fis.close();

out.write(bos.toByteArray());

out.writeInt(10);

out.close();
```

***********************SERVLET SIDE***********************

```
InputStream is = (InputStream) req.getInputStream();

DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);
System.out.println("NAME US :" + dis.readUTF());
System.out.println("NAME US 1:" + dis.readUTF());

File f = new File("D:\\temp2.txt");
f.createNewFile();

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);

byte[] fileBytes = new byte[1024];
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

while (true)
{
    int ch = dis.read(fileBytes);

    if (ch != -1)
    {
        bos.write(fileBytes, 0, ch);
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
fos.write(bos.toByteArray());

System.out.println(dis.readInt());
```

I am getting output as 
Hello
World
Also File is successfully copied to mentioned location temp2.txt

I am getting problem in line  System.out.println(dis.readInt()); as EOF reached.

Where I am doing mistake, and How to read data from DataInputStream.

Thanks.

Comment: Error stack trace please

Comment: java.io.EOFException
 at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:375)
 at TestServlet.doPost(TestServlet.java:59)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at

Comment: You can edit the post to add more details. Do not paste errors,code in comment

Answer (score 0):

Your loop loops until your stream is "empty", then you exit your loop. But afterwards you try to read from the stream again, which is empty and you are reaching eof.
What data do you want to print to sysout?

**edit**:

You can write directly to your `FileOutputStream` and rewrite your loop like this:

```
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(f);

byte[] fileBytes=new byte[1024];
int ch;

while(((ch = dis.read(fileBytes)) != -1) {
   fos.write(fileBytes,0,ch);
}
```

Comment: I want to send my data like this 

DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
out.writeUTF("Hello");
out.write(bytes) //Here I am writing File dat as Byte array.
out.writeUTF("World");

Now, I want to read the same at Servlet Side.
I am able to read 

DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(is);
System.out.println("NAME US :"+dis.readUTF());

dis.read() //

System.out.println("NAME US 1:"+dis.readUTF());

I am able to read first UTF and 2nd Write to File.

Problem is coming in 3rd read UTF as it is giving EOF Exception.

How to read Data in this Case?

Thanks

Comment: I am reading my file like this

  DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(is);
  System.out.println("NAME US :"+dis.readUTF());
  System.out.println("NAME US 1:"+dis.readUTF());

  File f=new File("D:\\temp2.txt");
  f.createNewFile();

  FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(f);

  byte[] fileBytes=new byte[1024];
  ByteArrayOutputStream bos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();


  while(true){
   int ch = dis.read(fileBytes);

   if(ch!=-1){
    bos.write(fileBytes,0,ch);
   }else{
    break;
   }
  }
  fos.write(bos.toByteArray());